# What are bag attributes and how can i generate them?

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, pkcs#12

while converting some certificates from keystore to openssl/pem I noticed for the first time that there are "Bag Attributes" prepended to the certs.

The look like this:

```
Bag Attributes
    friendlyName: CN=PositiveSSL CA,O=Comodo CA Limited,L=Salford,ST=Greater Manchester,C=GB
subject=/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=Comodo CA Limited/CN=PositiveSSL CA
issuer=/C=US/ST=UT/L=Salt Lake City/O=The USERTRUST    Network/OU=http://www.usertrust.com/CN=UTN-USERFirst-Hardware
```

Do they serve any function?

I noticed that I like them because they make my chain-files (a concatenation of certificates) more clear. Sadly the ca certs I download don't have them.

So how do I generate them?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To be exact, you apparently mean converting (or just reading) with the `openssl pkcs12 (import)` utility a PKCS#12 file, which can be supported by Java as a keystore but was not the default (update) until Java9 in 2017. PKCS#12 was designed and normally is used for a privatekey and the cert(s) (usually multiple) *for that key*, although the format is flexible enough to allow lone cert(s). OpenSSL *commandline* `pkcs12 -export` requires a privatekey, although it will add "extra" certs, and a program calling the *API* can apparently do no privatekey. In my experience, Java didn't support lone cert(s) in PKCS#12 before version 8, and in my 8 and 9 has *two* attributes: pkcs9.friendlyName and 2.16.840.1.113894.746875.1.1 which is apparently an Oracle-defined trustedKeyUsage. Most lone certs are not stored, or downloaded, as PKCS#12.

PKCS#12 is defined in terms of several (slightly different) "bag" structures that contain various things, primarily privatekeys and certs with optional attributes attached that are unsurprisingly called "bag attributes"; your case (apparently) has only cert(s). These attributes follow the now-conventional structure of an arbitrary number of pairs of OID plus value depending on the OID. Note in your display only `friendlyName` is a bag attribute, indicated because it is indented under the heading.

The `subject=` and `issuer=` lines are fields *from the cert itself* which the `openssl pkcs12 (import)` utility extracts and prints for convenience. If that is sufficient, you can display them for any cert with the `x509` utility; in particular if you want to have them before the PEM-encoded cert "blob" in the way `pkcs12` output does, use `openssl x509 -in infile -subject -issuer -out outfile`. This does *one* cert, so if you have a chain in a PEM file you need to split it apart and do each cert separately, and possibly combine again afterwards; for example something like

```
# split into files cert_1, cert_2, etc.
$ awk <chain.pem -va="openssl x509 -subject -issuer >cert_" 
  '/^-----BEGIN/{b=a (++n);x=1}x{print|b}/^-----END/{close(b);x=0}'

# output entire "bag" to stdout (with blank lines between certs)
$ awk <chain.pem -va="openssl x509 -subject -issuer" \
  '/^-----BEGIN/{b=a;x=1}x{print|b}/^-----END/{close(b);x=0;print""}'
```

As a comparison, `openssl s_client -showcerts` does something very similar: it outputs subject and issuer with each cert blob from the received chain, labelling them with a level number, "s:" and "i:".

Comment: Thanks! This is a more complete answer than I was hoping for.

Comment: Here's a lightly modified Bash script version that keeps the whole "bag"/"bundle" together rather than splitting it apart into multiple files: [`bagcerts` shell script](https://gist.github.com/dlenski/4af7088320def44711845fc1bd4b9e35)

Comment: Dan Lenski, your bagcerts script solved a very perplexing phpMyAdmin connection issue - I am very grateful!