# Get private key from PEM

Tags: java, ssl, https, openssl, pkcs#12

PEM file content.I have the passphrase of PEM file as well.

```
*Bag Attributes
    localKeyID: 12 7B 3C 4C ... 
subject=/C..OTHER FIELDS
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Bag Attributes
    localKeyID: 12 7B 3C 4C ..
Key Attributes: <No Attributes>
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----*
```

I am able to extract certificate from PEM file with command.

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in client.pem -out your-cert.crt
```

But I am not able to extract private key.Tried below listed commands. OpenSSL hangs for both the commands. Am I missing something obvious here ?

```
openssl pkey -in client.pem -out key.pem
```

I need to extract client cert and key file to create `SSLSocketFactory` object in java.

Comment: You should probably be using the `openss pkcs12 ...` command. Dave Thompson provides an `awk` command at [What are bag attributes and how can i generate them?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27515022/608639)

Comment: openssl pkcs12 command works with .pfx file but the file given to me is in PEM format.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: My bad; I thought you were trying to do this in C or Java. If you need help with unrelated commands, like `openssl` to convert a certificate, you should ask on another site in the stack exchange network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assumed commandline will prompt for entering the passphrase but it needs to be provided argument 
***-passin file:passphrase.txt***

openssl pkey -inform PEM -outform DER  -in client.pem -passin file:passphrase.txt  -out key.pem