# What are bag attributes in .pemfiles and do they matter in the file? I mean can use .pem files without bag attributes?

Tags: http, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

**Hello there,**
Currently working on a problem containing .pem file. The structure of the file is given as below:

```
Bag Attributes
     values
Key Attributes
     values
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
    key
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

So, do the bag attributes and key attributes matter in use? If yes, what is their purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bag attributes are generated by OpenSSL during PFX conversion to PKCS#1/PKCS#8 PEM private key files. These attributes are not signed and are completely optional. See this thread for more information: [What are bag attributes and how can i generate them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27515022/what-are-bag-attributes-and-how-can-i-generate-them)